# SSL Issue with Google Pixel Test Device

Tags: android, ssl

The application that I maintain is coming out with a new feature, while working in the devlopment environment I need to use a vpn to get to the apis that we are using.  For this service the vpn is required or it will not work.  This isn't a problem with all of my other test devices but with the google pixel we keep getting this ssl issue.  Putting a trust all SSL method is not an option either.  Has anyone ran into this problem on the Pixel yet or no a fix to it.

com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.